# Drag objects with the mouse

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to move and rotate any visible objects. But after dragging and rotating objects are defined in their old places.

The mouse cursor changes when it is over the object.

Tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
public class Main extends Application {  
    Point2D offset;  
    Shape selected;  

    @Override  
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {  
        Pane root = new Pane();  
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(40, 20, 50, 100);  
        rect.setRotate(90);  
        Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse(450, 450, 50, 25);  
        ellipse.setRotate(45);  
        Circle circle = new Circle(250, 250, 50);  
        root.getChildren().addAll(rect, ellipse, circle);  

        root.setOnMousePressed(e-> {  
            offset = new Point2D(e.getX(), e.getY());  
            e.consume();  
        });  

        root.setOnMouseMoved(e-> {    
            for(Node node: root.getChildren()){  
                if(node.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())){  
                    selected = (Shape) node;  
                    root.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);  
                    break;  
                }else{  
                    selected = null;  
                    root.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);  
                }  
            }  
            e.consume();  
        });  

        root.setOnMouseDragged(e-> {    
            if(selected != null){  
                selected.setTranslateX(e.getX() - offset.getX());  
                selected.setTranslateY(e.getY() - offset.getY());  
            }  
            e.consume();  
        });  

        Scene scene = new Scene(root,500,500);  
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);  
        primaryStage.show();  
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        launch(args);  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not handling the initial translation appropriately. You'd need to include this in your calculations for these value:

- substract from the mouse position before checking `contains` in `onMouseMoved`
- substract from the mouse position when calculation `offset`

However I recommend setting the cursor for the children of `root` instead of doing this in an event handler and also not checking the clicked node yourselt, but use the `target` provided by `MouseEvent`:

```
Point2D offset;
Node selected;
Point2D translateStart;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Pane root = new Pane();
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(40, 20, 50, 100);
    rect.setRotate(90);
    Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse(450, 450, 50, 25);
    ellipse.setRotate(45);
    Circle circle = new Circle(250, 250, 50);
    root.getChildren().addAll(rect, ellipse, circle);

    rect.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
    circle.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
    ellipse.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);

    root.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
        Node target = (Node) e.getTarget();
        if (target != root) {
            // event occured on a child
            selected = target;
            offset = new Point2D(e.getX(), e.getY());
            translateStart = new Point2D(selected.getTranslateX(), selected.getTranslateY());
        } else {
            selected = null;
        }
        e.consume();
    });

    root.setOnMouseDragged(evt -> {
        if (selected != null) {
            selected.setTranslateX(evt.getX() - offset.getX() + translateStart.getX());
            selected.setTranslateY(evt.getY() - offset.getY() + translateStart.getY());
        }
        evt.consume();
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Coordinates figures do not change.                                                   System.out.println(selected);                                                  **Circle[centerX=250.0, centerY=250.0, radius=50.0, fill=0x000000ff]**

Comment: Of course the coordinates do not change if you move the node using `translateX` and `translateY`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How to move the pieces on the coordinates?

Comment: By setting those values instead of the translate values and also using the initial positions instead of `translateStart`. You cannot handle them the same way though, like in the code above, since a `Rectangle` doesn't have a `centerX` property. I suggest using mouse eventhandlers for the `onMousePressed` event of the `Shape`s that does not consume the event and uses the command pattern to set the correct handling for the event. (You could be e.g. a `Consumer<Point2D>`)